# PHP SVN Client/Server

Tags: php, svn, open-source, repository, package

Is there a package or a way in **php** to add an **svn repository** to my web site?
Or something equally?

Like *codeplex*, *google code*, etc...?

> I need to insert a "`labs`" section
>   with my open source code, editable and
>   "submittable" for all.

Thanks a lot,
alberto.

Comment: What are you looking for in an answer that is not already stated in  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=svn+php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [svn extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php), or you can call svn over [the command line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php).

Comment: Have you used it at all?  It's marked as experimental and I've always been reluctant to trust anything to it.

Comment: command line should be fine. SVN commands are soooo simple.

Comment: Yes, I did make a deploy script using it. I don't recall having any issues. But I usually just drop to command line, since I don't want to add the dependency. Don't be scared away by the "experimental" tag in php - A lot of stuff is marked as such, but works just fine.